# CLLocation altitude property validity in flight

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, cllocationmanager, altitude

I understand the concept of negative for below sea levels and positive for above + there is vertical accuracy to check the sanity of this value.

I am interested in GPS data in a flight. What could be the max or approx max value of `altitude` so that I can differentiate Flight from road travel.

I understand I can query the speed but speed itself won't solve the purpose.

Comment: GPS is disabled [above 18,000 feet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinating_Committee_for_Multilateral_Export_Controls); you would need to reference the ground level at the location to determine if you are on the surface or not

Comment: @Paulw11 Would it be safe to assume that maximumOf(the highest motorable road in the world OR highest bridge) + 100m buffer = Plane Data?

Comment: Probably, but you could still be in a plane at a much lower altitude.  For example, anything about 770m is flying where I am but 10 minutes away you have to be at 1100m to be flying.

Comment: How did you find these stats: "anything about 770m is flying where I am". Your current above sea level + some buffer?

Comment: Because I know that my house is at 770m above sea level.

Comment: @Paulw11 GPS is not disabled above 18,000 feet.  I recently measured altitude using GPS on a recent flight at 39,000 feet.  There's no reason to disable it at any altitude.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to determine flight from GPS altitude is to lookup the ground elevation of the current location (latitude/longitude) in a database.  If the GPS altitude is greater then the user is in flight (or in a tall building).

This takes a very large database but the data is available.  This is probably not practical for most apps.  Look for DEM data (digital elevation model) databases such as SRTM, ASTER (see [here](https://gisgeography.com/free-global-dem-data-sources/))

Another method would be to detect take off.  If you are only interested in flight in jet aircraft, you would need to detect acceleration in a straight line from <10 knots to >100 knots, and then if the GPS altitude climbs by > 1000 fpm, you are likely in a jet taking off (although most prop planes can also climb >1000fpm).

Detecting all kinds of flight (airships, hot air balloons, light aircraft) gets more difficult.  It's hard to distinguish between an aircraft and a car climbing mountains, though it is possible with various heuristics.  It would also be difficult to distinguish a hot air balloon vs a tall building, low horizontal motion and both cases elevation is above ground level.

Comment: As of now I was able to eliminate Train data using OSM database and will try the DEM model in near future. Thanks for the intuitive comment.